# Plot wind vectors with quiver()

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot wind vectors. I use Basemap and this example http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plotting_data.html#quiver.
In my file, the longitudes go from 0 to 360. I use latlon=True to shift it to -180:180. But, when I use "points" to define the point density, the vectors are plotted over half of my figure only. 
Here is the code:
Of course, I use this code:

```
m=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlat=80, llcrnrlon=-40,urcrnrlon=40,resolution='c')
latvar=nc.variables['lat']
lat=latvar[:]
lon=nc.variables['lon'][:]
X,Y=m(lon,lat)
lons,lats=meshgrid(lon,lat)
X4,Y4=m(lons,lats)
varU=ncU.variables['var1'][0,0,:,:]
varV=ncV.variables['var2'][0,0,:,:]
speed=np.sqrt(varUvarU+varVvarV)
yy=np.arange(0,len(Y[:]),3)
xx=np.arange(0,len(X[:]),3)
points=np.meshgrid(yy,xx)
m.quiver(X4[points],Y4[points],varU[points],varV[points],speed[points],cmap=cmap‌​,latlon=True)
```

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, we can't, because you haven't shared the code you wrote with us. Put the smallest amount of code possible in this post to demonstrate the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of things going on that I am not sure you need. I have tried your code with some minor modifications and it works:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lon  =NC.variables['lon'][:]  
lat  =NC.variables['lat'][:]

m=Basemap(projection='cyl',,llcrnrlat=30,urcrnrlat=80, llcrnrlon=-40,urcrnrlon=40,resolution='c')

lons,lats=numpy.meshgrid(lon,lat)
X4,Y4=m(lons,lats)

varU=NC.variables['var1'][0,0,:,:]
varV=NC.variables['var2'][0,0,:,:]

speed=numpy.sqrt(varU*varU+varV*varV)

yy=numpy.arange(0,len(lat),3)
xx=numpy.arange(0,len(lon),3)

points=numpy.meshgrid(yy,xx)

m.quiver(X4[points],Y4[points],varU[points],varV[points],speed[points],cmap=cmap,latlon=True)
plt.show()

# with all points for comparison
m.quiver(X4,Y4,varU,varV,speed,cmap=cmap,latlon=True)
plt.show()
```